# Monitorar método no ionic 4

Tags: ionic

Bom dia.

No meu código tenho um método descrito abaixo:

```
public async DownloadOperacaoCodigos() {

this.total = 0;
this.contador = 0;

// this.loading.presentNoDuration('Carregando Códigos de Operação');
this.loading.present();

//carrega dados
this.modelOperacao = new Operacao();  
debugger;  
this.operacaoDbService.GetAll()
  .then(async (result: any) => {        

    this.total = result.data.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {

      this.modelOperacao = new Operacao();

      var operacaoCodigo = result.data[i];

      this.modelOperacao.gid = operacaoCodigo.gid;
      this.modelOperacao.grupo = operacaoCodigo.grupo;
      this.modelOperacao.codigo = operacaoCodigo.codigo;
      this.modelOperacao.nome = operacaoCodigo.nome;
      this.modelOperacao.descricao = operacaoCodigo.descricao;

       await this.operacaoLocalService.Add(this.modelOperacao);

      this.contador += 1;          

      if (this.total == this.contador ) {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.toastCtrl.presentToast('Dados de operação baixado com sucesso.');
      }
    }                

  })
  .catch((error: any) => {
    this.loading.dismiss();
    this.toastCtrl.presentToast('Erro ao inserir dados de operação no dispositivo.');
  });
```

Ele demora um determinado tempo para rodar, isso não é problema, demora mesmo.

A dúvida seria: Eu consigo monitorar em qualquer lugar do app esse processo? O usuário sai da página e exibir algo que o processo esta rodando ainda?

Answer (score 0):

Já passei por algo parecido na inicialização do meu app, consegui resolver mudando o consumo do api de Promise para Observable ficaria algo do tipo.

api.service.ts

```
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
    ....
   get(endpoint: string, headers?: HttpHeaders , params?: any): Observable<any>{

    if(!headers) {
      headers = this.setHeaders();
    }
    if(!params){
      params = this.setParams();
    }
     const OPTIONS = {
      headers:   headers,
      params:    params
      };        

      return this.http.get(`${endpoint}`,   OPTIONS  ) ;
    }
```

app.component.ts

```
...
this.apiService.get('/user').subscribe(
_result => this.user = _result);
```

...

Com isso meu app executou várias outras tarefas sem eu precisar esperar... porém caso você precise do resultado na hora então você precisa utilizar ele assim:

```
 this.apiService.get('/user').subscribe(
    _result => { 
          if(_result) {
                       .... coloca sua lógica aqui

                     }
               });
```

Também sou iniciante e espero ter ajudado.